# after clicking on one rectangle, make the other rectangle change color

Tags: c++, api, winapi, gdi

I display 6 circles (text in each circle) and 6 stars, when you click on a certain circle, a certain asterisk should light up, and the circle itself should disappear.
The first question- in each circle there should be a random letter.  I seem to have made the implementation, and at first glance it is correct, but instead of random letters, "M" always appears

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqHls.jpg)

```
case WM_CREATE: //the message will appear when creating a window
        char arr[strSize1];

        for (int i = 0; i < strSize1;i++)
        {
            char ch = rand() % 127;
            
                arr[i] = ch;
        }
```

the second question, in fact, I can not realize that when you click on the circle, a certain asterisk lights up.  The asterisk only lights up if I cllick on it.

````
#include <ctime>
#include <cmath>


struct Cell {
    int x, y;
    
    struct rgb {
        int r, g, b,z;
    }
    mainColor,
        borderColor,
        circleColor,
        textColor,
        circleSize,
        starSize,
        starColor,
        circleBorderColor;
    
};

HWND hWnd;
HDC hdc;
HPALETTE hPal;
BOOL bForceBkgd;
COLORREF color;
HBRUSH brush;




const int rectSize = 90;
const int circleSize = 40;
const int starSize = 40;

int y = 0, x = 0, yCoord, xCoord;
char buf[50];

bool flag = 0;
Cell cells[7][7];
HINSTANCE hInst; //Дескриптор програми
LPCTSTR szWindowClass = "QWERTY";
LPCTSTR szTitle = "  ";
// Попередній опис функцій
ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance);
BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int);
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);


bool isInCircle(int x, int y, int x0, int y0, int R) {

    if (pow((x - x0), 2) + pow((y - y0), 2) <= pow(R, 2)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;

}

bool isInStar(int x, int y, int x0, int y0, int R) {

    if (pow((x - x0), 2) + pow((y - y0), 2) <= pow(R, 2)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;

}


// main program
int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    MSG msg;
    // window class register
    MyRegisterClass(hInstance);
    // creating a program window
    if (!InitInstance(hInstance, nCmdShow))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
    // messages processing cycle
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return msg.wParam;
}
ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wcex;
    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW; 
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = (WNDPROC)WndProc; 
    wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wcex.hInstance = hInstance; 
    wcex.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_SHIELD); 
    wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW); 
    wcex.hbrBackground = GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_WINDOW + 3); 
    wcex.lpszMenuName = NULL; 
    wcex.lpszClassName = szWindowClass; 
    wcex.hIconSm = NULL;
    return RegisterClassEx(&wcex); 
}
// FUNCTION: InitInstance (HANDLE, int)

BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
    HWND hWnd;
    hInst = hInstance; 
    hWnd = CreateWindow(szWindowClass, // window class name
        szTitle, // program name
        WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_SYSMENU, 
        400, // position on x
        0, // position on y
        718, 
        790, 
        NULL, 
        NULL,
        hInstance, 
        NULL); 
    if (!hWnd) 
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow); 
    UpdateWindow(hWnd); 
    return TRUE;
}
// FUNCTION: WndProc (HWND, unsigned, WORD, LONG)
void DrawRectangle(HWND hWnd)
{
    HBRUSH hBrush;
    HDC hdc;
    RECT rect;
    
    SetRect(&rect, cells[2][6].x * rectSize, cells[2][6].y * rectSize + circleSize, (cells[2][6].x + 1) * rectSize, (cells[2][6].y + 1) * rectSize + circleSize);
    hBrush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(rand() % 256, rand() % 256, rand() % 256));
    hdc = GetDC(hWnd);
    FillRect(hdc, &rect, hBrush);
    ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdc);
    DeleteObject(hBrush);
}
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    
    RECT rt;
    HPEN pen;
    
    static unsigned short index = 0, index1 = 0, strSize = 257;
    static char* str = new char[strSize];
    static unsigned short const strSize1 = 6;


    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CREATE: //the message will appear when creating a window
        char arr[strSize1];

        for (int i = 0; i < strSize1;i++)
        {
            char ch = rand() % 127;
            
                arr[i] = ch;
                
            
        }
        
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
            {
                //serial numberoftheelement
                cells[i][j].x = j;
                cells[i][j].y = i;
                
                cells[i][j].mainColor.r = 0;
                cells[i][j].mainColor.g = 0;
                cells[i][j].mainColor.b = 0;

                //setting the grid color
                cells[i][j].borderColor.r = 40;
                cells[i][j].borderColor.g = 40;
                cells[i][j].borderColor.b = 40;
                
                //setting the colorofthe circle
                cells[i][j].circleColor.r = rand() % 256;
                cells[i][j].circleColor.g = rand() % 256;
                cells[i][j].circleColor.b = rand() % 256;
                //setting textcolor
                cells[i][j].textColor.r = rand() % 256;
                cells[i][j].textColor.g = rand() % 256;
                cells[i][j].textColor.b = rand() % 256;
                //setting circleSize
                cells[i][j].circleSize.z = 1 + rand() % (30 - 1);
                
                cells[i][j].starColor.r= 0 ;
                cells[i][j].starColor.g= 0 ;
                cells[i][j].starColor.b= 0 ;
                
            }
        }
        break;

    case WM_PAINT: //redraw the widow
        hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps); //start graphical output
        GetClientRect(hWnd, &rt);
        SetBkMode(hdc, TRANSPARENT);
        SetPolyFillMode(hdc, WINDING);
        
        
        
        
        //cycle of creating a grid with circles
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
            {
                //Setting a custom pen and fill for the grid
                pen = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 5, RGB(cells[i][j].borderColor.r, cells[i][j].borderColor.g, cells[i][j].borderColor.b));
                brush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(cells[i][j].mainColor.r, cells[i][j].mainColor.g, cells[i][j].mainColor.b));
                SelectObject(hdc, brush);
                SelectObject(hdc, pen);

                //Meshing
                Rectangle(hdc, cells[i][j].x * rectSize, cells[i][j].y * rectSize + circleSize, (cells[i][j].x + 1) * rectSize, (cells[i][j].y + 1) * rectSize + circleSize);

                
                //Remove Penand Mesh Fill
                DeleteObject(pen);
                DeleteObject(brush);

                //Setting a custom pen and fill for circles
                
                if (i < 1 && j < 6) {
                    //int z = 1 + rand() % (30 - 1);
                    //int z = 10;
                    pen = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 5, RGB(cells[i][j].circleBorderColor.r, cells[i][j].circleBorderColor.g, cells[i][j].circleBorderColor.b));
                    brush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(cells[i][j].circleColor.r, cells[i][j].circleColor.g, cells[i][j].circleColor.b));
                    SelectObject(hdc, brush);
                    SelectObject(hdc, pen);
                    
                    //Making circles
                    Ellipse(hdc, cells[i][j].x * rectSize + cells[i][j].circleSize.z, cells[i][j].y * rectSize + cells[i][j].circleSize.z + circleSize, (cells[i][j].x + 1) * rectSize - cells[i][j].circleSize.z, (cells[i][j].y + 1) * rectSize - cells[i][j].circleSize.z + circleSize);

                    //Remove pen and circle fill
                    DeleteObject(pen);
                    DeleteObject(brush);
                    

                    
                    // text output
                    SetTextColor(hdc, RGB(cells[i][j].textColor.r, cells[i][j].textColor.g, cells[i][j].textColor.b));
                    TextOut(hdc, cells[i][j].x * rectSize + 40, cells[i][j].y * rectSize + circleSize + 39, &arr[i], 1);
                    
                }

                if (i>0 && j>5) {
                    //int z = 1 + rand() % (30 - 1);
                    
                    pen = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 5, RGB(cells[i][j].starColor.r, cells[i][j].starColor.g, cells[i][j].starColor.b));
                    brush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(cells[i][j].starColor.r, cells[i][j].starColor.g, cells[i][j].starColor.b));
                    SelectObject(hdc, brush);
                    

                    //Making circles
                    
                    POINT poly[6];

                    poly[0].x = cells[i][6].x * rectSize + 60;
                    poly[0].y = cells[i][6].y * rectSize + circleSize + 28;
                    poly[2].x = cells[i][6].x * rectSize + 20;
                    poly[2].y = cells[i][6].y * rectSize + circleSize + 40;
                    poly[2].x = cells[i][6].x * rectSize + 60;
                    poly[2].y = cells[i][6].y * rectSize + circleSize + 52;
                    poly[3].x = cells[i][6].x * rectSize + 35;
                    poly[3].y = cells[i][6].y * rectSize + circleSize + 20;
                    poly[4].x = cells[i][6].x * rectSize + 35;
                    poly[4].y = cells[i][6].y * rectSize + circleSize + 60;
                    poly[5].x = cells[i][6].x * rectSize + 60;
                    poly[5].y = cells[i][6].y * rectSize + circleSize + 28;
                    Polygon(hdc, poly, 6);
                    
                    
                    //Remove pen and circle fill
                    DeleteObject(pen);
                    DeleteObject(brush);


                    

                }
                //Displaying text on the screen
                

                
            }
        }

        
            
        
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        break;

    case WM_MOUSEMOVE:

        y = HIWORD(lParam);
        x = LOWORD(lParam);
        rt.top = 7;
        rt.left = 0;
        rt.right = 7 * rectSize;
        rt.bottom = circleSize;
        

        break;

    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:

        yCoord = y;
        xCoord = x;

        yCoord -= circleSize;
        yCoord /= rectSize;
        xCoord /= rectSize;

        
        
        //Checking if coordinates are included in circle coordinates
        if (xCoord <7 && yCoord <7 && isInCircle(x, y - circleSize, xCoord * rectSize + rectSize / 2, yCoord * rectSize + rectSize / 2, (rectSize - 20) / 2)) {
        
            
            
                cells[yCoord][xCoord].starColor.r =50 ;
                cells[yCoord][xCoord].starColor.g=70 ;
                cells[yCoord][xCoord].starColor.b=200 ;
            
            cells[yCoord][xCoord].circleColor.r = 0;
            cells[yCoord][xCoord].circleColor.g = 0;
            cells[yCoord][xCoord].circleColor.b = 0;
            cells[yCoord][xCoord].circleSize.z = 1 + rand() % (30 - 1);

            cells[yCoord][xCoord].textColor.r = 0;
            cells[yCoord][xCoord].textColor.g = 0;
            cells[yCoord][xCoord].textColor.b = 0;
            //InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);
            //brush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(5,5,5));
            SetRectEmpty(&rt);
            InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);
            
            
            //DeleteObject(brush);
            DrawRectangle(hWnd);
            GetPixel(hdc, x, y);
            
            flag = 1;
        }
        
        break;
    

    case WM_DESTROY:                //completion of work
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        //Processing messages that are not processed by the user
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
} ```
````

Answer (score 0):

There are two reasons why random coordinates do not appear:

The first is that your `arr` array is initialized again when the `WM_PAINT` message is triggered, instead of the random value you set.So you need to modify it to static:

```
static char arr[strSize1];
```

The second reason is that when you call the `TextOut` function, the parameter passed is `&arr[i]`, and i is always 0 in the statement, so the same letter is always displayed. You should modify it to `&arr[j]`:

```
TextOutA(hdc, cells[i][j].x * rectSize + 40, cells[i][j].y * rectSize + circleSize + 39, &arr[j], 1);
```

In `WM_PAINT`, you incorrectly modified the value of `poly[2]` twice, but did not set the value of `poly[1]`, you should modify it to:

```
poly[0].x = cells[i][6].x * rectSize + 60;
poly[0].y = cells[i][6].y * rectSize + circleSize + 28;
poly[1].x = cells[i][6].x * rectSize + 20;
poly[1].y = cells[i][6].y * rectSize + circleSize + 40;
poly[2].x = cells[i][6].x * rectSize + 60;
poly[2].y = cells[i][6].y * rectSize + circleSize + 52;
poly[3].x = cells[i][6].x * rectSize + 35;
poly[3].y = cells[i][6].y * rectSize + circleSize + 20;
poly[4].x = cells[i][6].x * rectSize + 35;
poly[4].y = cells[i][6].y * rectSize + circleSize + 60;
poly[5].x = cells[i][6].x * rectSize + 60;
poly[5].y = cells[i][6].y * rectSize + circleSize + 28;
```

When you press the left button to trigger the `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` message, the subscript of the circle you are dealing with is the same as the subscript of the star, but their coordinate mapping relationship is not the same. And you should judge that it is within the subscript range of the circle Instead of `xCoord <7 && yCoord <7`.

The modified code is as follows:

```
if (xCoord < 6 && yCoord == 0 && isInCircle(x, y - circleSize, xCoord * rectSize + rectSize / 2, yCoord * rectSize + rectSize / 2, (rectSize - 20) / 2)) {
    cells[xCoord + 1][yCoord + 6].starColor.r = 50;
    cells[xCoord + 1][yCoord + 6].starColor.g = 70;
    cells[xCoord + 1][yCoord + 6].starColor.b = 200;
    cells[yCoord][xCoord].circleColor.r = 0;
    cells[yCoord][xCoord].circleColor.g = 0;
    cells[yCoord][xCoord].circleColor.b = 0;
    cells[yCoord][xCoord].circleSize.z = 1 + rand() % (30 - 1);
    cells[yCoord][xCoord].textColor.r = 0;
    cells[yCoord][xCoord].textColor.g = 0;
    cells[yCoord][xCoord].textColor.b = 0;
    //InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);
    //brush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(5,5,5));
    SetRectEmpty(&rt);
    InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);
    //DeleteObject(brush);
    DrawRectangle(hWnd);
    GetPixel(hdc, x, y);
    flag = 1;
}
```

In the end it successfully worked for me:

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer, i'm incredibly grateful

Comment: @Маlnyy Hi,if this answer did help to you, please feel free to mark it to help people with the same issue, and let me know if you have any problem.Thanks.